# CMake Error: No CMAKE_RC_COMPILER could be found

Tags: c++, c, cmake, rc

I have installed Windows on a virtual machine to debug a game i'm developing primarily on Linux (I haven't used Windows since i was 9 years old). I use CMake to build it, and i have installed LLVM+CLang for compiling. CMake complains about a missing "RC Compiler" which i cannot find to install anywhere on the web. The error thrown is "No CMAKE_RC_COMPILER could be found." What should I do?

Comment: I think you need the windows SDK from Microsoft. [https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/menurc/using-rc-the-rc-command-line-](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/menurc/using-rc-the-rc-command-line-)

Comment: What distribution of Clang? The official one is not self-sufficient on Windows, and needs either MinGW or MSVC. Assuming MinGW, `CMAKE_RC_COMPILER` is supposed to point at `windres`, which should come with MinGW.

Comment: If you prefer Clang+MinGW, [install MSYS2](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30069830/2752075) and use it to install both GCC and their build of Clang. They also provide a [pure libc++ environment](https://www.msys2.org/docs/environments/) without GCC, if that's what you want.